# Getting data from API faster (multiple calls)

Tags: python, api, python-requests

I'm trying to gather sensor reads from a SCADA. I can access to this data using an API but it is limited and it only allows getting data of one sensor in each call, so if i have thousands of sensors and each call takes 3-5 seconds it takes too much time to collect all I need.

For this purpose i've created a python script that has a loop and it downloads the data for each sensor and concatenate each sensor data to a dataframe but as i said i takes too long. It looks like this:

```
for ninv in sensor_array:       
        base_url = 'https://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
        params = {
            'deviceid': ninv,
            'valueids': inv_data,
            'from': date_from,
            'to': date_to,
            'resolution': '15min',
    
        headers = {'Authorization':'Bearer '+token,}
        response = session.get(base_url, headers=headers, params=params)
        df_aux = pd.DataFrame(response.json())
        df_datasensors = pd.concat([df_datasensors, df_aux], axis=0)
```

Is there any solution to improve this and get everything in less time? I've heard about multiprocessing but don't know how to implement it here.

Thanks!

Comment: You can send requests parallel which should be faster. Check [`ThreadPoolExecutor` Example](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#threadpoolexecutor-example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This example will give you the idea how to use `multiprocessing.Pool` with `requests.get` (the basic idea is to use `Pool` to get the Json data and in the main thread construct dataframe from this result, append it to the list and as a final step, concat all dataframes together):

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd
from multiprocessing import Pool


def get_data(params):
    ninv, inv_data, date_from, date_to, token = params

    base_url = "https://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
    params = {
        "deviceid": ninv,
        "valueids": inv_data,
        "from": date_from,
        "to": date_to,
        "resolution": "15min",
    }

    headers = {
        "Authorization": "Bearer " + token,
    }

    response = session.get(base_url, headers=headers, params=params)
    return response.json()


if __name__ == "__main__":

    # construct this data programatically (from the sensor_array?)
    data = [
        ("ninv1", "inv_data1", "date_from1", "date_to1", "tkn"),
        ("ninv2", "inv_data2", "date_from2", "date_to2", "tkn"),
        ("ninv3", "inv_data3", "date_from3", "date_to3", "tkn"),
        ("ninv4", "inv_data4", "date_from4", "date_to4", "tkn"),
        ("ninv5", "inv_data5", "date_from5", "date_to5", "tkn"),
    ]

    all_dfs = []
    with Pool(4) as pool:  # <-- 4 is the number of processes to use
        for result in pool.imap_unordered(get_data, data):
            all_dfs.append(pd.DataFrame(result))

    df_final = pd.concat(all_dfs)
    print(df_final)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried something similar but with the function in other file .py. And before the request in the main code i need to do some thing and when I start the pool with it tries to execute the before code again and again and i want to execute with pools only the function...

Comment: I was using it wrong. It works great now. Thanks you so much, it helped me a lot!